# Set "options snd-hda-intel model=generic" fixed sound output on headphone, but didn't work for speaker on Ubuntu 22.04 and 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 and both have no sound output on built-in speaker and headphone. I was able to fix sound output on headphone by running the following command

```
echo "options snd-hda-intel model=generic" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

However, my built-in speaker still didn't work. I tried `model=auto` and `model=dual-codecs`, but still no luck. I assume if I can find the correct model. It would make both of the speaker and headphone works. I tried to find the model in https://docs.kernel.org/sound/hd-audio/models.html, but my laptop is a rare brand, which is Sager NP8872T with Realtek High Definition Audio ALC1220.

Here are some Audio and sound card info

```
$lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_intel          53248  7
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_codec         163840  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_hda_core          110592  9 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_pcm               143360  12 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd                   106496  25 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi


$lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio
0000:00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller [8086:51c8] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device [1558:67f5]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
--
0000:01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:2288] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:0000]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

Alsamixer output
[HDA Intel PCH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrCon.png)
[HDA NVidia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ds1rp.png)

Side note: I tried the reinstalled alsamixer, pulseaudio, and pauvcontrol. None of them worked.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm having same issue ripping my hair out trying everything. Let me know if you found a solution

Answer (score 1):

I got it fixed. Here is the link where I found the solution. [Hdajackretask: cannot get internal speakers working without hijacking headphones](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231058/hdajackretask-cannot-get-internal-speakers-working-without-hijacking-headphones)

My audio issue was not caused by the sound card. It was my chipset ALC1220 was not configured properly when boot from Ubuntu.
Run the following command fixed the audio issue on ACL1220 for me.

```
echo "options snd-hda-intel model=clevo-p950" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

Both speaker and headphone works perfectly fine for me. If this doesn't work for you, you can look the model for your audio chipset.